# How can I add a new column based on two dataframes and conditions for big data?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

How can I add a new column based on two dataframes and conditions?

For example, if df2['x'] is between df1['x']±10 and df2['y'] is between df1['y']±10 and for same year, give 1 otherwise 0.

The codes below worked with relatively small data. But when I  used it for big data (df1=210.548 rows, df2= 301,661 rows), I got error message: "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically".

Are there any other ways to solve it? You can find sample dataframes and expected output in this question: [How can I add a new column based on two dataframes and conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328410/how-can-i-add-a-new-column-based-on-two-dataframes-and-conditions/71329046#71329046)

```py
merged = df1.merge(df2, on="year", how="left", suffixes=("1", "2"))
merged["f"] = (
    (merged.x2 >= merged.x1 - 10)
    & (merged.x2 < merged.x1 + 10)
    & (merged.y2 >= merged.y1 - 10)
    & (merged.y2 < merged.y1 + 10)
)
dataset = (
    merged.groupby(["x1", "y1", "year1", "a", "b", "f"])
    .f.any()
    .astype(int)
    .reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following dataframes:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "x": [40.1, 50.1, 60.1, 70.1, 80.1, 90.1, 0, 300.1],
            "y": [100.1, 110.1, 120.1, 130.1, 140.1, 150.1, 160.1, 400.1],
            "year": [2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004],
        }
    )
    .sort_values(["year", "x", "y"])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(df1)
# Output
       x      y  year
0   40.1  100.1  2000
1   50.1  110.1  2000
2   60.1  120.1  2001
3   70.1  130.1  2001
4    0.0  160.1  2003
5   80.1  140.1  2003
6   90.1  150.1  2003
7  300.1  400.1  2004
```

```py
df2 = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "x": [92.2, 30.1, 82.6, 51.1, 39.4, 10.1, 0, 299.1],
            "y": [149.3, 100.1, 139.4, 111.1, 100.8, 180.1, 0, 402.5],
            "year": [1950, 1951, 1952, 2000, 2000, 1954, 1955, 2004],
        }
    )
    .sort_values(["year", "x", "y"])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(df2)
       x      y  year
0   92.2  149.3  1950
1   30.1  100.1  1951
2   82.6  139.4  1952
3   10.1  180.1  1954
4    0.0    0.0  1955
5   39.4  100.8  2000
6   51.1  111.1  2000
7  299.1  402.5  2004
```

Here is what your code, given minor fixes, outputs:

```py
      x1     y1  year  f
0   40.1  100.1  2000  1
1   50.1  110.1  2000  1
2   60.1  120.1  2001  0
3   70.1  130.1  2001  0
4    0.0  160.1  2003  0
5   80.1  140.1  2003  0
6   90.1  150.1  2003  0
7  300.1  400.1  2004  1
```

But you can achieve the same result without expensive `merging` and `groupby` operations, like this:

```py
# Find common years between df1 and df2
year_match = set(df1["year"]).intersection(df2["year"])

# Slice both dataframes on common years and align indexes
s1 = df1[df1["year"].isin(year_match)]
s2 = df2[df2["year"].isin(year_match)].set_index(s1.index)

# Initialize new "f" column
df1["f"] = 0

# Update "f" column according to given conditions
mask = (
    (s2.x >= s1.x - 10) & (s2.x < s1.x + 10) & (s2.y >= s1.y - 10) & (s2.y < s1.y + 10)
)
df1.loc[mask.index, "f"] = 1
```

So that:

```py
print(df1)
# Output
       x      y  year  f
0   40.1  100.1  2000  1
1   50.1  110.1  2000  1
2   60.1  120.1  2001  0
3   70.1  130.1  2001  0
4    0.0  160.1  2003  0
5   80.1  140.1  2003  0
6   90.1  150.1  2003  0
7  300.1  400.1  2004  1
```

Comment: for the line "s2 = df2...", it gave an error message "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 301661 rows, received array of length 170058"

Comment: I guess this means that, while the toy dataframes df1 and df2 you provided in your post are of identical shapes (8, 3), your real dataframes are not (df2 number of rows > df1 number of rows). So, this is a different question and solving it suppose to know how you want to deal with these "surplus" values. Cheers.